# How do I setup and run SparkR projects and scripts (like a jar file)?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

We have successfully gone through all the SparkR tutorials about setting it up and running basic programs in RStudio on an EC2 instance.

What we can't figure out now is how to then create a project with SparkR as a dependency, compile/jar it, and run any of the various R programs within it.

We're coming from Scala and Java, so we may be coming at this with the wrong mindset. Is this even possible in R or is it done differently that Java's build files and jars or do you just have to run each R script individually without a packaged jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do you just have to run each R script individually without a packaged jar?

More or less. While you can create a R package(-s) to store reusable parts of your code (see for example `devtools::create` or [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)) and optionally distribute it over the cluster (since current public API is limited to high level interactions with JVM backend it shouldn't be required), what you pass to `spark-submit` is simply a single R script which:

- creates a `SparkContext` - `SparkR::sparkR.init`
- creates a `SQLContext` / `HiveContexts` - `SparkR::sparkRSQL.init` / `SparkR::sparkRHive.init`
- executes the rest of your code
- stops `SparkContext` - `SparkR::sparkR.stop`

Assuming that external dependencies are present on the workers, missing packages can installed on the runtime using if not `require` pattern, for example:

```
if(!require("some_package")) install.packages("some_package")
```

or

```
if(!require("some_package")) devtools::install_github("some_user/some_package")
```

Comment: would please take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001256/should-i-pre-install-cran-r-packages-on-worker-nodes-when-using-sparkr